# How can I connect to all types of databases using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql

I have a little question. I am looking for a mode to connect to all types of databases using php and I don't find anything usefull. For example I am developing a platform and it will be on all kinds of databases like Mysql or PostgreSQL or others.

Comment: [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) is a **built-in** abstraction/API for connecting to diverse database servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Comment: Yes it is! I use it with CodeIgniter PHP Framework all the time

Answer (score 4):

PHP's PDO extension has [many drivers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) though some (Oracle for example) are marked *experimental*.

The database adapter class in Zend Framework does a particularly good job at abstracting connection details.

Comment: I've read about this but isn't what I need. I need something portable , something to work on any hosting. ODBC needs drivers and other things.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it also requires different SQL syntax depending on the database server

Comment: Not really ... from what I've seen sql syntax is the same.

Comment: @Petah That's true in some circumstances (`LIMIT` queries for example) which is why I mentioned the ZF component. It takes care of most eccentricities.

Comment: @Badea To connect to any database, you're going to need the appropriate extension(s) installed even when using an abstraction layer. PHP has no native DB connectivity

Answer (score 1):

Use and abstract database library such as http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Database protocols don't have a standard like HTTP does. To create something like this, you would need to create an implementation for every database. Given the number and diversity of them, this would be very difficult.